# POST not finishing before .then() runs in async call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flask, async-await, fetch

I'm making a POST request that takes ~10 seconds to finish... but my alert displays immediately on click, before the server returns 200. Why? And how do I fix it to wait until the server completes operation?

```
const handleClick = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("/create", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(highlights),
    }).then(alert("hi!"));
};
```

If I change my .then to
 `.then(() => {alert("hi!");})` as was suggested below, the page flashes/seems to refresh when the server request is made *but the alert doesn't show at all*

Update:

If I use this code:

```
const handleClick = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch("/create", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(highlights),
        });
        alert("first");
    } catch (error) {}
    alert("second");
};
```

The second alert fires right when the button is pressed, the first alert never fires.

Answer (score 2):

Async/await is introduced to overcome the then/catch chaining issue. You dont need to use then , you have to use try/catch. async/await always used with try/catch only.

```
const handleClick = async () => {
try{
    const response = await fetch("/create", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(highlights),
    })
alert("hi!")
}
catch(error){}
}
```

When you use try/ catch , control will not go further until i/o call is finished. So you can put alert or any code out of try catch block also. It will be executed once await call is completed.
Like this

```
try{
    const response = await fetch("/create", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(highlights),
    })

}
catch(error){}
}
alert("hi!")
```

---

Try this.

If you are using reactjs and nodejs, then I have simulated your requirement and it is working as expected.
I have used reactjs hooks.
Alert gets trigger once post call is succeeded.

You can check this out.
https://github.com/ajaysikdar/reactjs-nodejs-alert

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is actually not true to my understanding. As an Async function always returns a promise (its just syntactic sugar over promises), and .then() and .catch() work well. (Your solution also doesn't change the behavior)

Comment: @Lumen async and await is a _replacement_ for promise chains. You need to await the promise. Don't use `then`. You say await is syntactic sugar, but what is it syntactic sugar for if you still have to use `then`?

Comment: @JMadelaine understood. This still does not solve my core problem, however. Any ideas? to be clear about my issue: if I simply "await", the server request runs and nothing after it (in this case, the alert) is run.

Comment: Are you sure you've implemented it correctly? This answer looks correct to me. The alert must be inside the async function, and after the await.

Comment: how are you firing this function? If it is a submit button of a form, make sure you are using `e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: I'm calling it using the onClick handler from a button that is *not* part of a form.

Comment: I've just updated the question with the suggested syntax showing exactly the code im using and behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
.then(() => { alert("hi"); });
```

The `then` function expects you to pass it a function, but you are actually *calling* a function (`alert`), and passing the return value of that function to `then`.

Comment: No dice. In this case, I don't even get the alert. The page flashes before the server operation completes, almost appearing like a re-render.

Comment: @Lumen Sounds like this is inside a form and you aren't preventing the default submit

Comment: @charlietfl It is not inside a form, but I am not handling default submit in anyway. Does that apply in this case?